# CSS overriding style, but revert to original if nested

Tags: css

I created a very basic modal for my Vue app to display messages. I want to reuse the basic logic and style for a modal that contains other Vue components, so I add a class to the wrapper to change the style of it. This modal with components can have other message modals which should then use the default style again. What is the best way to achieve this without repeating the basic style in a nested style:

```css
.modal-mask {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    display: table;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
    z-index: 100;
}
.modal-wrapper {
    display: table-cell;
}
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #333333;
    margin: 10vh auto;
    max-height: 90vh;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    width: 400px;
}
.modal-dynamic .modal-content {
    width: fit-content;
    padding: 0;
}
/* is there a better way to reset it to the .modal-content style defined first */
.modal-content .modal-content {
    padding: 20px;
    width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-mask modal-dynamic" aria-role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-wrapper">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <SOME HTML MARKUP>
            <div class="modal-mask" aria-role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-wrapper">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        Some message
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this case it's only two properties, but if there are more it gets cumbersome and hard to maintain. So a "reset" would be great.

Comment: As I got an edit suggested that I rejected: Vue isn't relevant for this question, as I now just pass this "flag" as a prop to the modal component, but it still interests me, how this could be done with HTML and CSS only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your html provided you can simply used: `.modal-dynamic > .modal-wrapper > .modal-content`

### DEMO

```css
.modal-dynamic > .modal-wrapper > .modal-content {
    width: fit-content;
    padding: 0;
}
.modal-mask {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    display: table;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
    z-index: 100;
}
.modal-wrapper {
    display: table-cell;
}
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #333333;
    margin: 10vh auto;
    max-height: 90vh;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    width: 400px;
}
/*.modal-dynamic .modal-content {
    width: fit-content;
    padding: 0;
}*/
/* is there a better way to reset it to the .modal-content style defined first */
/*.modal-content .modal-content {
    padding: 20px;
    width: 400px;
}*/
```

```html
<div class="modal-mask modal-dynamic" aria-role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-wrapper">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!--<SOME HTML MARKUP>-->
            <div class="modal-mask" aria-role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-wrapper">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        Some message
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, thought I didn't mention that there are some divs in between for the lightbox effect. But this gives me some ideas how it might still work out

Comment: Then provide html please

Comment: @Thomas Based on your html provided you can simply used: `.modal-dynamic > .modal-wrapper > .modal-content`